# Is there any research showing how effective HIIT (specifically stationary bike) is for fat loss?

Tags: weight-loss, hiit

I'm doing HIIT for VO2 improvement and wondering if that'll help with fat loss as well.

I've read a lot of conflicting reports, including one fellow who said "there a study on this that will be published soon" (but no date on th article (arrggg!).

Answer (score 6):

Found [this research](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0026049594902593)

Which compared Endurance Training vs. HIIT showing that relative to the energy expended, HIIT was 9x as effective in reducing fat.

(This isn't exactly the comparison I was looking for but it's a good start)

But this [other study contradicts that](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002822395001816)

> This study suggests that fat loss is a function of energy expended
>   rather than exercise intensity.

Comment: I think making it relative to energy use is skewing the results. Most HIIT I know, e.g. tabata, use a lot less energy than an endurance workout. I'm also skeptical of that result, as I've read more that says lower intensity is better for burning fat.